# Best way to do dual observation in python

Tags: python

I don't know the official term for it so I'll just call it "dual observation".
Suppose I have a class (this is overly simplified):

```
class Room:
  def __init__(self, west, east, north, south):
    self.west = west
    self.east = east
    self.north = north
    self.south = south
```

In my code I would define some rooms like this:

```
room2 = Room(east = room1)
room1 = Room(west = room2)
```

This throws an error because `room1` isn't defined yet when defining room 2. I solve this by setting room1 to None beforehand, but I realize that when I want to do something like `player.location` in the case that the player is in room2 (would return room2) and I tell the player to go east, they just go to None.

What would I need to do the make sure the rooms are synced with each other, hence why I call it a dual observation. I don't want to automatically make it so every room's west is that room's east because I don't want to limit myself to that, so I'm wondering what is the best way to achieve this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Create `room2` with `None` like you are. Then you can set the value of `room2.east = room1` after you've created `room1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than make the linkage part of the initialization of a room, delegate that to a separate function that takes *both*, uninitialized rooms as arguments.

For example,

```
def add_passage(r1, dir1, rm, dir2):
    setattr(r1, dir1, r2)
    setattr(r2, dir2, r1)


room1 = Room()
room2 = Room()
add_passage(room1, 'east', room2, 'west')
```

The interface presented by `add_passage` could be improved, but the basic idea is to separate the idea of *creating* a room from *connecting* it to another room.

Note that this doesn't restrict you to "straight" passages; you could leave `room1` via the east door to reach `room2`, but take the *south* door from `room2` to return to `room1`:

```
add_passage(room1, 'east', room2, 'south')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly initially define it as `None` and then change. Look my example:

```
class Room:
  def __init__(self, west=None, east=None, north=None, south=None):
    self.west = west
    self.east = east
    self.north = north
    self.south = south
```

The class will automatically set the directions as `None` unless you give then a value. Then I create the rooms, first `room2`, then `room1` and just then I add `room1` to `room2.east`:

```
room2 = Room()
room1 = Room(west = room2)
room2.east = room1
```

Then I tested:

```
print(room2 is room1.west)
print(room1 is room2.west)
print(room1 is room2.east)
```

The output was, as expected:

```
True
False
True
```